# Function Not Returning Decimal Places despite being cast as decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the little bit of code below that is not returning a decimal place for the formula so instead of something like 4.55 I'm only getting a 4.00 any help would be appreciated thank you.

`CAST(datediff(mi,ord_startdate,ord_completiondate)/60 as decimal (10,2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing integer division (`60` vs `60.0`) and casting the result of that division as `decimal(10,2)`. Try this instead:

```
CAST(datediff(mi,ord_startdate,ord_completiondate)/60.0 as decimal (10,2))
```

Comment: Will do, thank you. I will update when I check this.